# Guardar datos de un select2 - Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual quiero guardar la/s profesion/es de los usuarios, para ello estoy utilizando select2, pero no se como guardar los datos seleccionados en una tabla intermedia profesion_user, ya que profesion y user tienen una relacion de muchos a muchos

```
<label>Profesion</label>
<select class="select2bs4" name="profesion[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
     @foreach($profesion as $id => $profesion)
        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ in_array($id, old('profesion', [])) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $profesion }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function create()
{
    $profesion = Profesion::all()->pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('profile.edit', compact('profesion'));
}
```

Las relaciones están definidas de la siguiente manera: 
Modelo user

```
public function profesiones()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profesion::class);
}
```

y en el modelo profesion

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(user::class);
    }
```

Intente de la siguiente manera:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $data = User::create($request->all());
    $data->profesiones()->sync($request->input('profesion', []));

    return redirect()->route('perfil.index');
}
```

pero me da "Array to string conversion" de error

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: @Shaz ya agregue como estuve probando, pero no me funciona

Comment: ¿qué muestra `dump($request->input('profesion', []))`?

Comment: en la function store coloco?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente manera mandale el id de la profecion

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $data = User::create($request->all());
        $data->profesiones()->sync($request->profecion_id);
    
        return redirect()->route('perfil.index');
    }
```